# Core Data Optimize Fetch Request

Tags: core-data

This Fetch Request takes almost 10 seconds to execute on iPhone.
The goal is to fetch 1 random thumbnail from each category.
setting fetchlimit = 1 most of the times return the same thumbnail so I have to fetch all photos from each category.

Any ideas ?

```
    [categoriesArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id object, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop) {

    NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Photos"];
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"place.subcategory.category == %@", object];
    [request setPredicate:predicate];
    NSError *error;
    NSArray *photosManagedObjectsArray = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

    NSUInteger randomIndex = arc4random() % [photosManagedObjectsArray count];

    NSManagedObject *photoObject = [photosManagedObjectsArray objectAtIndex:randomIndex];
    UIImage *photoImage = [UIImage imageWithData:[photoObject valueForKey:@"thumbnail"]];   
    UIImage *resizedImage = [photoImage imageCroppedToFitSize:CGSizeMake(IMAGE_WIDTH, IMAGE_HEIGHT)];
    [imagesArray addObject:resizedImage];
    [objectsArray addObject:photoObject];

}];
```

many thanks! 
Bill.

Comment: Try using `fetchOffset` property of `NSFetchRequest` as a random integer from 0 to (numberOfPics - 1)

Comment: thanks, I was totally ignoring fetchOffset.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to pull all your objects into an array. Just change

```
NSArray *photosManagedObjectsArray = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];`
NSUInteger randomIndex = arc4random() % [photosManagedObjectsArray count];
```

to this

```
NSUInteger count = [managedObjectContext countForFetchRequest:request error:&error];
NSUInteger randomIndex = arc4random() % count;
```

Now use `fetchOffset` to grab just the single object you need.

```
[request setFetchOffset:randomIndex];
[request setFetchLimit:1];
```

Comment: Many Thanks. I was totally ignoring fetchOffset existence.