# iOS: Generate random object ID

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I want to use this method to fetch a random entity of core data:

```
randomQuote = [managedObjectContext objectWithID:randomID];
```

But I don't know how to set a random ID, which is an instance of NSManagedObjectID. Could anyone help me?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10656106/core-data-optimize-fetch-request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
NSFetchRequest *myRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[myRequest setEntity: [NSEntityDescription entityForName:myEntityName inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext]];
NSError *error = nil;
NSUInteger myEntityCount = [managedObjectContext countForFetchRequest:myRequest error:&error];    

NSUInteger offset = myEntityCount - (arc4random() % myEntityCount);
[myRequest setFetchOffset:offset];
[myRequest setFetchLimit:1];

NSArray* objects = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest error:&error];    
id randomQuote = [objects objectAtIndex:0];
```

Comment: Thanks! One step forward, I want to achieve a function named "Quote of the Day". Meaning the quote is randomly selected each day, instead of changing each time opening the app. Any suggestions on that?

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to generate uuid:

> ```
>     NSString *uuid = [[NSUUID UUID] UUIDString];
> ```